# Keep track of progress while precaching assets with the Workbox

Tags: service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Imagine we have N assets that need to be pre-cached with a service-worker once user navigated to the web site. We have appropriate `precache-manifest.js` with listed N-files and we are using [workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([...])](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.precaching#.precacheAndRoute) to configure needed behavior (default [CRA](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/) setup)

Is there a way to keep track of precaching progress when using [workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.precaching#.precacheAndRoute) or [workbox.precaching.precache](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.precaching#.precache)?

I imagine it could be something like passing a parameter-callback function to the `workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute` along with the array of entries to precache. And this callback is invoked for each cached entry..

Is there any solution or workaround for this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar requirement. I want to be notified when all the items are cached succesfully!

Answer (score 0):

There is no event or callback provided by workbox to notify if precaching is completed. But here is a workaround i've managed to come up with using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) to notify the client that precaching is completed.

```
// sw-precache.js
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest)

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    caches.open(workbox.core.cacheNames.precache).then(cache => {
        cache.keys().then(keys => {
            if (keys.length >= self.__precacheManifest.length) {
                clearInterval(interval)
                self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
                    clients.forEach(client => client.postMessage('afterPrecache'))
                })
            }
        })
    })
}, 1000)
```

And in your client,

```
// index.html
....
navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
    if (e.data === 'afterPrecache') {
        // precaching completed
    }
}
....
```

You can even tweak the above solution to get track of precaching progress.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it should be possible to add your own [custom plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins#custom_plugins) to the precaching component using [addPlugins](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-precaching#.addPlugins)

I hope to have a play with proving this theory at some point soon using cacheDidUpdate event, I am not certain that I can communicate the progress easily back to the page though. The doubt in my mind is whether I can reliably listen to any messages in the page that is registering, but not yet controlled by the precaching serviceworker